# Images dont slide in orbit slider Foundation

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation, orbit

I'm trying to add Foundation Orbit Slider to my web page. It looks easy and I've got to see the images and the prev & next buttons, but if I click on prev and next buttons the orbit slider doesn't move at all. The images doesn't slide and I don't know why, beacuse I've seen many examples and I think my code looks the same. Any help woud be appreciated

```
<html>
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="altiria webapp">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/foundation.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.structure.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.css">
    <script src="assets/js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/foundation.min.js"></script> 

 </head>

 <body>
   <div class="orbit-container">
     <ul class="example-orbit" data-orbit>
       <li>
         <img src="assets/images/paisaje1.jpg" alt="slide 1" />
         <div class="orbit-caption">
           Caption One.
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <img src="assets/images/paisaje2.jpg" alt="slide 2" />
        <div class="orbit-caption">
          Caption Two.
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="assets/images/paisaje3.jpg" alt="slide 3" />
        <div class="orbit-caption">
          Caption Three.
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Navigation Arrows -->
    <a href="#" class="orbit-prev">Prev <span></span></a>
    <a href="#" class="orbit-next">Next <span></span></a>

    <!-- Slide Numbers -->
    <div class="orbit-slide-number">
    <span>1</span> of <span>3</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Timer and Play/Pause Button -->
    <div class="orbit-timer">
      <span></span>
      <div class="orbit-progress"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <!-- Bullets -->
 <ol class="orbit-bullets">
   <li data-orbit-slide-number="1"></li>
   <li data-orbit-slide-number="2" class="active"></li>
   <li data-orbit-slide-number="3"></li>
 </ol>

 <script>  
  $(document).foundation();
 </script>

</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a mix of the pre-rendered HTML and rendered HTML on your page. You don't need the chunks of code labeled with comments (navigation arrows, slide numbers, timer, bullets, etc); Foundation will render them for you.

In addition, it's possible that your `class="example-orbit"` is interfering and, unless you need it, I'd suggest removing it.

Important to note: According to the Foundation website, "Orbit has been deprecated, meaning that it is no longer supported." They [officially recommend](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html) using a different image slider instead of their orbit.

Comment: You were right Stephanie. I've decided to use Slick and I've got good results. But I'm having troubles to set the width of the image. I'm goint to open a new post because I'm really stuck. Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok, I've just fixed that issue. I can set the width  just by adding a css class to all images and setting width: 1000px; It seems to be working right